# Cannot add 2 pointers

Tags: c++, delphi

My code is straightforward and seemed to be very easy like

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <windows.h>
#define ADDR_cabalbase 0x01083A90
#define ADDR_ONat 0x35c 
#define ZeroOFS 0x0
int main()
{


    if ((*reinterpret_cast<PDWORD *>(ADDR_cabalbase)+*reinterpret_cast<PDWORD *>(ZeroOFS))
        + *reinterpret_cast<PDWORD *>(ADDR_ONat)
        == 3){
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
}
```

But it gives an error:

```
Error   1   error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong. I just want to re-write a Delphi function in C++

```
procedure TWanda.Timer5Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    if PDWORD(PDWORD(PWORD(cabalbase)^+$0)^+ONat)^ = 3 then
    begin
      timer9.Enabled:= true;
    end;
  except {ignore errors} end;
end;
```

Comment: You cannot add pointer to pointer, that does not make any sense, it is not clear what that code does in delphi

Comment: A pointer contains the location of an address in memory, much like an envelope contains a postal address.  Adding postal addresses don't make sense just as adding pointers doesn't make sense.  You can add an *offset* to a pointer.

Comment: Please do not put pictures of code in your question. Just paste the code as text.

Comment: `ADDR_ONat` and `ZeroOFS` look to be offsets. Just add them to the pointer and don't use *reinterpret_cast<PDWORD *>() for these. I would have calculated the address and put it in a PDWORD variable before the if ().

Comment: @drescherjm you are right, I posted the right code, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to re-write a Delphi function in C++

The Delphi code is casting numeric values to `PWORD` (pointer to `WORD`) and `PDWORD` (pointer to `DWORD`), but you are casting everything to `PDWORD*` (pointer to pointer to `DWORD`) instead.  You need to drop the `*` since `PDWORD` is already a pointer.  And the first cast of `cabalbase` is to a `PWORD`, not a `PDWORD`.  Dereferencing a `PWORD` reads 2 bytes, whereas dereferencing a `PDWORD` reads 4 bytes instead.  That makes a BIG difference.

This is the *correct* translation of the Delphi code:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define ADDR_cabalbase 0x01083A90
#define ADDR_ONat 0x35c 
#define ZeroOFS 0x0

int main()
{
    if (*reinterpret_cast<PDWORD>(*reinterpret_cast<PDWORD>(*reinterpret_cast<PWORD>(ADDR_cabalbase) + ZeroOFS) + ADDR_ONat) == 3) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would suggest using some local variables to make it easier to read (and debug):

```
int main()
{
    WORD w_cabalbase = *reinterpret_cast<PWORD>(ADDR_cabalbase);

    DWORD dw_cabalbase_ofs = *reinterpret_cast<PDWORD>(w_cabalbase + ZeroOFS);

    DWORD dw_onat = *reinterpret_cast<PDWORD>(dw_cabalbase_ofs + ADDR_ONat);

    if (dw_onat == 3) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`PDWORD` is an alias name for a **P**ointer to **DWORD**. You're casting `ADDR_cabalbase` (whatever its type is) to a *pointer to a `PDWORD`,* that is, to a pointer to a pointer to a `DWORD`. You then dereference that, obtaining a `PDWORD`, that is, a pointer to a `DWORD`. Then you try to add these together.

Comment: Dear downvoter, care to explain what's wrong with the answer? I'd be happy to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @drescherjm comment the solution is:

```
if (*reinterpret_cast<DWORD *>(ADDR_cabalbase+ZeroOFS
        + ADDR_ONat)
        == 0){

    }
```

Comment: This code is NOT the same logic as in the Delphi code. The Delphi code dereferences the `WORD` (not `DWORD`!) value located at the `cabalbase` address, THEN adds zero to that value, then casts the result to `PDWORD` and dereferences it to obtain a `DWORD` value, adds `ONat` to that value, casts the result and dereferences a `DWORD` value from it. Your code above is doing something difference. You are adding zero to `cabalbase` itself, not the `WORD` it points to. And you are not casting+dereferencing the `DWORD` value located at the address obtained after adding `ONat`.